# Translated words not showing child theme

Tags: child-theme, localization

I created a child theme for the twentyfourteen theme which I'm also busy translating into Afrikaans. I've named the file

> pietergoosen-af_AF.po

and placed it into the languages file and I've added the following into my respective files functions.php and wp-config.php

```
    function pietergoosen_language_file_registration() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'pietergoosen', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pietergoosen_language_file_registration' );
```

and

```
define('WPLANG', 'af_AF');
```

All the plugins I've translated shows the Afrikaans words, but my theme not. I've checked out all tutorials and answers on this site, but can't get the thing to work. To assist, here are the headers for my stylesheet and po file

```
   /*
Theme Name:             pietergoosen
Theme URI:              http://pietergoosen.com
Description:            Spesiaal geskep deur Pieter Goosen vir sy webtuistes.
Author:                 Pieter Goosen
Author URI:             http://pietergoosen.com
License:                GNU General Public License v2 or later
License                 URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Template:               twentyfourteen
Version:        1.0
*/

@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css");
```

and

```
   msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Pieter Goosen v1.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-02-03 19:25+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-02-03 21:32+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: Pieter Goosen <goosen_p@yahoo.com>\n"
"Language-Team: Private <goosen_p@yahoo.com>\n"
"Language: af\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.5\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: gettext;gettext_noop;__;_e;_n:1,2;_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: ..\n"

#: ../404.php:17
msgid "Not Found"
msgstr "Niks gevind"
```

Here is the header for my pietergoosen.pot and the first string

```
 msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Pieter Goosen v1.0\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-02-03 19:19+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-02-03 19:22+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: Pieter Goosen <goosen_p@yahoo.com>\n"
"Language-Team: Private <goosen_p@yahoo.com>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.5\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: gettext;gettext_noop;__;_e;_n:1,2;_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;\n"
"Language: English\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"

#: ../404.php:17
msgid "Not Found"
msgstr ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

in the following line after hours of researching for an answer. This little line is one thing that is left out by all tutorials and most answers

> Remember that your filenames have to be fr_FR.po & fr_FR.mo (depending on your language) and not domain-fr_FR.xx like the plugins do.

So I just changed the po and mo filenames accordingly